# Fedora: Hibernate doesn't work

Tags: fedora, sleep, hibernate

On Hibernate (i.e. KDE Kickoff - Leave - Hibernate), I immediately get a black screen with those two lines:
PM: Syncing file systems ...
Freezing user space processes ...

A few seconds later, the screen turns black, but instead of hibernating, the session is locked. When I move the mouse, I can enter my password and I'm back where I started. Only the NIC seems to be temporarily deactivated.

OS: Fedora 15
uname -r: 2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64
MB: Asus SABERTOOTH 990FX

Comment: Do you have a working swap partition?  (Post the output of `cat /proc/swaps` if you're not sure.)

Comment: Yes, I have a 5 GB swap partition.

Comment: Try the [debugging steps listed here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt) and let us know if they work or fail.

Comment: Upgraded to Fedora 16 (all updates installed), same issue. From your link: Neither one of those first two commands (echo reboot > /sys/power/disk...) hibernate my system. I can't be the only one having this problem...?

Comment: In that case, I would [file a bug against the kernel](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora&version=16&component=kernel).  Include all the details you can from the debugging steps you performed and complete information about your hardware.  (An easy way to provide a hardware profile is to run `smoltSendProfile` and provide the link it outputs in your bug.)

Comment: It was the swap partition after all (smaller than RAM, I should've mentioned the amount of physical memory). Sorry about the confusion, my bad. Patches, your very first comment was the right one. I'll write an answer so this can be marked as "answered", but if you would write an answer, I'd rather accept that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patches was actually right, it was the swap partition, which was too small (< RAM). I should have realized that.
All the other comments/answers are valuable too, thanks for all those tips.
@Patches, if you write an answer, I'll delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

Check your computers BIOS setup, - some have an option to set the suspend-level to either standby or hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are running an old version of the Linux kernel.
2. Hibernate on Linux, as of late, almost never works. To debug this problem will require you compile the kernel with  CONFIG_PM_DEBUG.
3. Most users can't debug these problems, so if you really want hibernation to work, you can consider changing to Ubuntu, but there is only a small chance this will help.

See this guide:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt